# trigger jobs based on list in the database

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Is it possible for Jenkins pipeline to execute the jobs based on the list in the mysql database table?

I currently have pipeline setup to read a file in git but would like to use the table list instead since we are already keeping the list in the table. It is just duplicate work trying to maintain both list.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in functionality to help you with this, but you should be able to create a script within your pipeline.

Create a new Jenkins job and in it, make a connection to your DB. You should then be able to extract the list of jobs by running SQL commands. At this point, you could either write the list into a file and read the file like you would have read the file in git, or you could recursively call `buildJob` and loop through the list, building each job as you go.

Since you are using MySQL, note that there is a [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/database-mysql/) which can make you life easier.